# LWUIT - Using Data in Theme get me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, lwuit, out-of-memory

I'm working with LWUIT 1.5 to make my own theme to apply to my J2ME application. I've found a problem when I've added datas to my theme from Data tab in LWUIT Resource Editor. Those data files are `.csv` files.

When I run my application, It show me `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in my Eclipse console and it doesn't start.

I've found that several of this data files are causing this problem because their sizes are more than 100.000 bytes. Does it means that I need to use data more small? Does it means that exist a maximum size to that resources?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: what is the size of your .JAR file & for which mobile you are testing it ?

Comment: Hi! @Lucifer finally I've decided to divide my file in several files. This file is used to create my local database into my device when the applicacion is runned the first time.
But it's so slowly (times about minutes, it depends the size of files). How knows what can I do to decrease these times?

Answer (score 1):

Basically `OutOfMemoryError` occurs on S40 mobiles. Because they have only heap memory 1 to 2 MB size. They can't extended their memory on run time. So when its exist, `OutOfMemoryError` exception will be throw. So better idea, If you handle huge size of files, just store it in server and read from server. Use [web service](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/) for this. Look on these articles, then you can get better idea about how to handle,

- [Memory Leaks In LWUIT And Tracking Memory In Java ME](http://www.lwuit.com/2008/06/memory-leaks-in-lwuit-and-tracking.html#ixzz1eWilkOJE)
- [Portability and Performance](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cehefjdi.html).

Comment: Hi again!Thank you so much bharath for your response. I would like to datail you two thing about my error:

1. I'm receiving my java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when execute my application with the emaulator, not in mobile.
2. My problem is that I need to have all recordstores in my device because my application must run without connection.

Maybe the only solution is to divide my file in several files?

What do you think?

Salu2!

Comment: Hi gain @bharath !

I've found where my problem happen. It is when I'm loading my LWUIT theme at this line:

Resources.open("/MyTheme.res");

I've attached to my theme seven files wich size are about 90-80KB and when my app execute this line it makes the Exception(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)

What can I do?

Comment: I think you are using images in your application. Right? Also convert the files doesn't matter, but size is the matter. :)

Comment: No! Your wrong sorry. I'm using database files to import my own database to my app. That files size are more than 1MB.